# Linux Page poisoning

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, arm

I am working on `ARM Linux`. When we enable `CONFIG_PAGE_POISONING`, the pages are filled with poison byte pattern after `free_pages()` and verifying the poison patterns before `alloc_pages()`.

This helps me to identify the bit flips or page memory corruption, by verifying the poison byte pattern before allocating a new page. But how to identify the culprit? I searched in google, but could not find.

Comment: Well CONFIG_PAGE_POISONING only help in finding out that something changed unallocated memory. Finding the perpetrator is a whole other subject. There are too many things which can actually cause something like that.

Comment: Yes. I understand that there are many other things which could have corrupted the page. But as a developer, we should identify the problem and resolve isn't it. What should be the approach in this situation?

Comment: If it is repeatable,you can `unmap` the memory or map as *read-only*; whoever writes will page fault.  It is possible that it is a hardware bug and there is no way that Linux (or the ARM CPU) can detect this.  For instance, it maybe DMA, it maybe a glitch on the SDRAM line when a certain bit pattern is written, it maybe a power supply issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I've just had a similar issue, and it took me a while to debug it. So I will recommend here on two tools that were very useful to me (I used both of them simultaneously):

**First tool: KMEMLEAK**

In order to enable it you must enable it in your kernel configuration:

```
CONFIG_HAVE_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK=y
```

And if you get this kernel log:

```
kmemleak: Kernel memory leak detector disabled
kmemleak: Early log buffer exceeded (xxxx), please increase DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_EARLY_LOG_SIZE
```

Then I also suggest to add this to your kernel configuration:

```
CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_EARLY_LOG_SIZE=4096
```

In addition I think you need to add `kmemleak=on` to the boot arguments (because I'm not sure it's enabled by default).

After all that, the KMEMLEAK tool is ready to run.
Now I suggest to give a look at the examples that are given in the links below. They helped me to understand how to use the (API and how to read it's logs):
[KMEMLEAK first example](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/images/stories/pdf/lceu11_marinas.pdf)
[KMEMLEAK second example](https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2017/11/06/tracing-memory-leaks-in-the-nfc-digital-protocol-stack/)

**Second tool: SLUB_DEBUG**

The SLUB_DEBUG is very useful with finding memory corruptions caused by use-after-free, double-free and buffer-overrun errors.

In order to enable it you should update your kernel configuration:

```
CONFIG_SLUB_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_SLUB_DEBUG_ON=y
CONFIG_PAGE_POISONING=y
```

And I also suggest adding:

```
CONFIG_ARCH_SUPPORTS_DEBUG_PAGEALLOC=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_PAGEALLOC=y
CONFIG_PAGE_OWNER=y
```

In addition you will probably need to add to the boot arguments the next flags: `page_poison=on, slub_debug=FZP` and if you've also set `CONFIG_PAGE_OWNER`, you also need `page_owner=on`.

After all the debug configuration is set, you should have a look at the next example. It's clear and useful.
[SLUB_DEBUG example](http://techvolve.blogspot.com/2014/04/slubdebug-detect-kernel-heap-memory.html)

**Good Luck finding your bug !!!**